# Find path of module without importing in Python

Tags: python

I've seen several approaches for finding the path of a module by first importing it. Is there a way to do this without importing the module?

Comment: Why? Why don't you want to import it?

Comment: Because importing is useless at the point in the program where the paths are needed and can cause circular dependencies and other issues. Import occurs at a more opportune time later down the road.

Comment: Also you may want to just look at the source code without actually running any code in the module.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Using [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html) module:

```
>>> import pkgutil
>>> package = pkgutil.get_loader("pip")
>>> package.filename
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg/pip'
>>> package = pkgutil.get_loader("threading")
>>> package.filename
'/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py'
>>> package = pkgutil.get_loader("sqlalchemy.orm")
>>> package.filename
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/sqlalchemy/orm'
```

In Python 3, use `pkgutil.get_loader("module name").get_filename()` instead.

Using [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module:

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.find_module('sqlalchemy')
(None, '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/sqlalchemy', ('', '', 5))
>>> imp.find_module('pip')
(None, '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg/pip', ('', '', 5))
>>> imp.find_module('threading')
(<open file '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py', mode 'U' at 0x7fb708573db0>, '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py', ('.py', 'U', 1))
```

N.B: with imp module you **can't** do something like `imp.find_module('sqlalchmy.orm')`

Comment: @cgohlke : actually their is no __pkutil__ package, it should be __pkgutil__, it was a typo mistake , thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @mouad I'm actually looking for the same thing. The above implementation with `pkgutil` doesn't do what is requested in all cases. `pkgutil.get_laoder("sqlalchemy.orm")` wll execute `sqlalchemy/__init__.py`, tho it won't execute `sqlalchemy/orm.py`.

Comment: @Prody: Yes that's true in case of a package it will execute the ``__init__.py`` package as the documentation (http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_loader) say **If the named module is not already imported, its containing package (if any) is imported, in order to establish the package __path__** which make total sense :)

Comment: I found [in Python 3.5.1] that package.filename didn't exist, but package.get_filename() did.

Comment: It sometimes doesn't work for Python3.11 . For example, how can I get the location of `os.py` (os stdlib) in Python3.11?

Answer (score 16):

For python3 `imp` is deprecated. Use pkgutil (as seen above) or for Python 3.4+ use [importlib.util.find_spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec):

```py
>>> import importlib
>>> spec = importlib.util.find_spec("threading")
>>> spec.origin
'/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py'
```

Comment: spec.origin attribute do not exist for a module folder which contains an `__init__.py`. Use instead :
 ```python
>>> spec.submodule_search_locations[0]
```

Comment: unfortunately `find_spec` might try importing the module https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ec2385e315fc6b28d92dfb4c97fefcbb1e7daa68/Lib/importlib/util.py#L94

Comment: This will only work if `find_spec` is not used to find submodules: `find_spec("foo")` will not import anything but `find_spec("foo.bar")` will import `foo` (thereby evaluating `foo.__init__.py`)

Comment: In Python3.11, spec.origin of "os" module returns "frozen"

Comment: @tamuhey that means the module was compiled into byte code and included in an a standalone python interpreter. i.e. it has no location

Answer (score 1):

For most use-cases, you actually don't need help from third parties. [`importlib.util.find_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec) has been around since python3.4, and solves the issue for top-level imports:

```py
>>> import importlib.util
>>> spec = importlib.util.find_spec("foo")
>>> spec.origin
/home/me/my_venv/python3.11/site-packages/foo/__init__.py
```

And for a portable variant that gets the parent folder:

```
[...]
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path(spec.origin).parent
/home/me/my_venv/python3.11/site-packages/foo
```

---

Notes:

- For sub-packages (e.g. `foo.bar`), parent packages will be actually imported. Due to the dynamic nature of python, including how imports may resolve, there is no correct solution which does not do an actual import (try to find the location of `os.path` without importing `os` for a real-world-example).
- If the package doesn't exist, `spec` will be `None`.
- If the package is actually a namespace, `spec.origin` will be `None`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try running this in your interpreter:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['codecs'].__file__ # codecs is just an example
'/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc'
```

Comment: +1 I would have suggested a DFS or something using os.system. But this is awesome - didn't know this could be done

Comment: This doesn't work except with some modules from the stdlib. Try it with SQLAlchemy. Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: this will not work for package which wasn't already been loaded.

Comment: The question explicitly asks "without importing it".

Answer (score 0):

```
import importlib.util 
import os

this_module='numpy'

origin=importlib.util.find_spec(this_module).origin
print(origin)

path_to_this_module=os.path.dirname(origin)
print(path_to_this_module)
```

Output on windows:

```
...\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py
...\site-packages\numpy
```

Output on linux:

```
/home/.../site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
/home/.../site-packages/numpy
```