# How to get the path of a module file without importing it

Tags: python, testing, mocking, tdd

I have inherited some code that I have to test, but unfortunately this code has not been written with the testability on mind (no dependency injection, no nothing), so I am facing some trouble.

## The scenario

The problem basically is the huge tree of dependencies: when I import the module where lives my code to be tested (let's call it `mymodule`), the imported modules, import some other modules and these do some imports as well (that automatically even do some connections to a DB). That's bad, but I could live with it mocking every module with the cool `mock` framework.

But the worst is, that the class I want to test (let's call it `MyClass`) inherits from another ORM-related class ... (let's call it `ORMBase`), and that totally destroys the testability of the code since many methods I want to test use some methods that come from this `ORMBase`. And I can't directly mock the `ORMBase` because the `class MyClass(ORMBase)` is executed at load time, not at runtime...

## The hacky solution

"Fortunately" I have found a hackish way to intercept the ORMBase before it is loaded, which consists of reading the `mymodule.py` file as text, identify the imports and mock them in the `sys.modules`. So, I change the `ORMBase` class for the `mock.MagicMock` class, and voilà I can perform tests.

## The real problem

I need the path in the hard drive of the `mymodule.py` file. As I beta-tried the hacky solution, I used a hardcoded file path, but this is not a long term solution. So I am trying to **find the path of a .py file without importing it**. I have seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693608/find-path-of-module-without-importing-in-python) that propose the use of the modules `pkgutil` and `imp`, but truth is, they do not keep the modules from loading.

Example:

```
assert 'zc' not in sys.modules, 'pre'

loader = pkgutil.get_loader('package.subpackage.module')

assert 'ab' not in sys.modules, 'post'
```

Will raise this exception:

```
assert 'ab' not in sys.modules, 'post'
AssertionError: post
```

So the next idea I have is to walk manually the pythonpath myself, and play with the folder/files till I find the path of mymodule.py, but I foresee some problems with this approach. Any better idea?

Thanks.