# Get installed package location (not local)

Tags: python, pip

I need to get the location of an installed package (i.e. from "site-packages" or "dist-packages"), but I may be inside the package's directory itself.

I have tried everything from both of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693608/find-path-of-module-without-importing-in-python), and some problems inevitably arise.

I have tried `pip.get_installed_distributions()`, and this is very close, but there is no guarantee that the package will have been installed with pip. If the package is not installed with pip, then `get_installed_distributions()` doesn't return the package.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
python -c 'import module; print module.__file__'
```

E.g:

```
$ python -c 'import ssl; print ssl.__file__'
/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.pyc
```

Compare to:

```
$ python -c 'import requests; print requests.__file__'
/home/lars/env/common/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I am inside the package directory. In other words, if I clone a package locally, and try to import the package while inside that directory, doing those commands will just give me the local location.

Comment: Isn't that the correct behavior, though? It's telling you the location of the module that Python would use if you were to run it from that directory.  Alternatively, you could `(cd /; python -c 'import module; print module.__file__')`.  Stick that in an alias and you're all set...

Comment: I will try to do this through Python (moving to root first), and see it that does the trick. It seems like a roundabout way to achieve this, but if it works it works