# Error pyodbc connecto sqlserver with python

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm trying to do a automate migration from `sqlserver` to `postgres`, so I tryed to use pyodbc then  installed it

```
pip install pyodbc
```

And after I try to do a connection with python with below code:

```python
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.0.12;DATABASE=Aval;UID=sa;PWD=1032')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from user")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row.user_id, row.user_name
```

The when I atempt to run it I get the following mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "migracion.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so
  Reason: image not found
```

**Environment Information:**

- **SO:** Mac yosemite
- **python version:** 2.7.10
- **pip version:** pip 7.1.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981376/i-uninstalled-matplotlib-tried-to-reinstall-it-and-it-failed-to-be-imported-o/31981566#31981566

Answer (score 2):

U need to install proper odbc

for mysql `brew install mysql-connector-odbc` and for postgres `brew install psqlodbc`