# How to find the file name contains a module in an egg file?

Tags: python, egg

I need to find a file contains the module from an egg file.

For example: module_name = "plugins"
And the return file within the egg file: "mypackage/plugins.py"

How to do that without importing the module?

Comment: You want to actually import the module?

Comment: Sorry i am not very clear about my question. I don't want to import the module.

Comment: Then maybe this leads you down the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693608/find-path-of-module-without-importing-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question..

Just use `importlib` and try to import the module.

```
from importlib import import_module

package_name = "mypackage"
try:
     module = import_module("{}.{}".format(package_name, "plugins")
except ImportError:
     # The module does not exist
```

If the module is importable, `module` will contain a reference to the initialised module. `module.__file__` will also give you the path to the python file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to import the module. I updated my question to reflect that.