# How to find "os" module file path in Python3.11 without importing it?

Tags: python, python-3.11

I can get the path of 'os.py' like this:

```py
import os
os.__file__
```

But how can I get it without importing it? I found [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693608/find-path-of-module-without-importing-in-python), but none of these work for **Python3.11** , although they work for Python<=3.10 .

It seems that the newly introduced Python3.11 optimizations ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#frozen-imports-static-code-objects)) broke these solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (though it seems that [resolve_name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.resolve_name) actually imports the module):

```
>>> osp = pkgutil.resolve_name("os")
>>> osp.__file__
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/os.py'
```

or

```
>>> from importlib.util import find_spec
>>> spec = find_spec('os')
>>> spec.loader_state.filename
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/os.py'
```

Comment: It seems that you're using Python3.10, not 3.11

Comment: @tamuhey Right. Updated

Comment: "though it seems that resolve_name actually imports the module" - well, yes; that `__file__` attribute is coming *from a `module` object*. The second method would certainly work *after* the module was imported by the first method; does it work separately, though?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it does